# How to change file/folder resource icons from existing eclipse views

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

I want to change the appearance of project explorer view in eclipse by changing the default file/folder icons for my custom plugin resources. I am aware of Decorators - https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html , But how can I change the existing icons itself inspite of just putting an overlay or underlay image?

Also I don't want to create a new view , just want to reuse the project explorer with my icons.

Answer (score 0):

The main icon used is taken from the default editor used for the file as defined by the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point.

If you defining new file types and editors you can specify the icon, but you can't override the icon for existing types and editors.

Comment: I think you can use `IPipelinedTreeContentProvider` to remove existing items from the explorer and replace them with new ones (in this case same text, different icon).

Answer (score 0):

To modify existing project explorer content first add a `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer` extension point. Under that add a `viewerContentBinding` element with the id `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer` (that's the id of the standard Eclipse project explorer view).

Under that add a `(includes)` with a `contentExtension` element. The pattern identifies the IDs of navigator content to include and can contain wildcards, e.g. `com.example.mycontent.*`.

Next define a `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent` extension point with a `navigatorContent` element. Make sure the id you provide matches the above pattern. Set the content and label providers. If the content provider implements `IPipelinedTreeContentProvider` it will allow you to modify existing content (possibly wrapping things like IFolder inside classes your label provider understands). You'll also need to define `triggerPoints` to identify the items for which your content provider should be called.

It may be useful/necessary to suppress standard navigator content. You can do this by specifying an `override` element under `navigatorContent` with the policy `InvokeAlwaysRegardlessOfSuppressedExt` and id `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent`.