# how to change particular directory icon in project explorer in eclipse plugin in using java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there anyway to dynamically change directory icon or directory color in project explorer in eclipse plugin project using java code[image]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718357/how-to-change-file-folder-resource-icons-from-existing-eclipse-views